# Select GTK theme in Wine-staging under Plasma 5

Tags: wine, theme, plasma5, gtk3

I am using Plasma 5 with the dark default theme and would like to have dark-themed apps under Wine as close as possible to the main one. I had [some](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCkgA.png) success by using msstyles with `winecfg`, but I have seen also that Wine staging has an option to enable gtk3 theme support

[image]

After that, the applications running under Wine are supposed to follow the desktop theme. That seems to be the case - as said [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/foobar2000/comments/4mecl6/foobar2000_wine_staging_gtk3_theming_arcdark/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3), showing Foobar2000 with Arc-Dark gtk theme:

[image]

But that is under Gnome.

Plasma 5 settings for GTK theme under **Settings - Application style - Gnome/GTK...** are not followed by Wine, and instead some default dark theme is used, which is not the GTK theme set above (Breeze-Dark) and which is not changing no matter what GTK theme is selected in Settings:

[image]

Is this "Wine-staging-GTK3-theme-support" feature limited to GTK desktops?

---

```
Kubuntu 20.04
Plasma 5.18
wine-6.22 (Staging)
```